# Intel SGX: Reproduce enclave measurement from enclave binary

Tags: sgx, trusted-computing

I have a question about the enclave measurement in Intel SGX. Judging by the SignTool [source code](https://github.com/01org/linux-sgx/blob/master/sdk/sign_tool/SignTool/sign_tool.cpp#L156) (and high-level description in the manual), it seems like measurement involves loading the enclave file (ELF or PE). But the result of loading varies on different platforms, right? I wonder if I can reproduce consistent enclave measurement from an enclave binary.

In particular, I'm considering the following scenarios: Suppose I want to distribute an `enclave.signed.so` to my users and I only want to serve requests from that particular enclave. I guess I can't simply compare the local measurement on my platform with users' (can be included in their attestations). What should I do instead?

Essentially the question boils down to how to link the binary and the measurement cryptographically? There seems to be a paradox: suppose I have the enclave binary, the only way I can get its measurement is to load it. However, the loading process is **not** trusted (done by OS)! How can I ensure the measurement I get is indeed for that particular binary? I must have misunderstood something because this seems critical to the entire validity of SGX. Please correct me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, to establish the "real" enclave measurement you need a trustworthy system.

The measurement of an enclave is done by the processor. It permutes the measurement value with each enclave creation steps/instruction. The [specification](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf) explains this permutations in quite some detail. For example the pseudo code of ECREATE contains this statement about the measurement field:

```
(* Initialize hash updates etc*)
Initialize enclave’s MRENCLAVE update counter;
(* Add “ECREATE” string and SECS fields to MRENCLAVE *)
TMPUPDATEFIELD[63:0] = 0045544145524345H; // “ECREATE”
TMPUPDATEFIELD[95:64] = DS:TMP_SECS.SSAFRAMESIZE;
TMPUPDATEFIELD[159:96] = DS:TMP_SECS.SIZE;
TMPUPDATEFIELD[511:160] = 0;
SHA256UPDATE(DS:TMP_SECS.MRENCLAVE, TMPUPDATEFIELD)
INC enclave’s MRENCLAVE update counter;
```

Assuming theses descriptions are exhaustive and one knows the order in which the creation steps are executed by the driver, one should be able to compute an enclave's measurement **without loading it**. Thus, you could compute the value in an enclave. But how would compute the measurement of this enclave?